# How to round to nearest Thousand?

Tags: php

How Do I round a number to its nearest thousand?

```
function round($var) {
    // Round it
}
```

Comment: Use [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Comment: round up to power of 10, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43932648/6521116

Answer (score 70, accepted):

PHP allows negative precision for `round` such as with:

```
$x = round ($x, -3); // Uses default mode of PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP.
```

Whereas a positive precision indicates where to round *after* the decimal point, negative precisions provide the same power *before* the decimal point. So:

```
n    round(1111.1111,n)
==   ==================
 3   1111.111
 2   1111.11
 1   1111.1
 0   1111
-1   1110
-2   1100
-3   1000
```

As a general solution, even for languages that don't have it built in, you simply do something like:

- add `500`.
- divide it by `1000` (and truncate to integer if necessary).
- multiply by `1000`.

This is, of course, assuming you *want* the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` behaviour. There are some who think that bankers rounding, `PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, is better for reducing cumulative errors but that's a topic for a different question.

Comment: Add 499, or add 500?  Shouldn't 500 round up to 1000?

Answer (score 8):

```
rounded_number = round(original_number, -3);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 7):

Just a small change, may help to round up!

```
$x = ceil(220.20 / 1000) * 1000;
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer to round up to the next thousand:

`abs(round(($a - 500), -3)) . "\n";`

500-999 then round to 0 and 1000-1999 round to 1000, etc.

If you want it to start at 1000, then just do

`abs(round(($a + 500), -3)) . "\n";`

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [round function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) as mentioned by other posters `round($number, -3)`.

You can also, divide your number by 1,000, round to nearest whole number then multiply by 1,000.

Also, if you want to round up, you can divide by 1,000, negate the quotient, coerce it to an integer, negate it again and then multiply it by 1,000.

Answer (score 3):

Just for your information simple calculation from [Mikel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150001/how-to-round-to-nearest-thousand/5150075#5150075) is faster than [round()](http://php.net/en/round):

```
Test name       Repeats         Result          Performance     
calculation     10000           0.030229 sec    +0.00%
round           10000           0.040981 sec    -35.57%
```

Test source [here](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/RoundToNearestThousand.php).

Answer (score 2):

from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

```
$x = round ( $x, -3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

For positive integers:

```
function round($var) {
    return ($var + 500) / 1000 * 1000;
}
```

Comment: OP asked for it to be called `round()`.  If it already exists, call it something else! ;-)