# Can Twig round numbers up to the nearest thousand?

Tags: twig

The Twig documentation for [number rounding](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html) talks about rounding decimals, but I have a case where I want to round a number like 19,995 to 20,000. Is there a tricky way to round up to nearest thousand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `round` filter accepts negative precision. ([Just like in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150021/2387151))

```
{{ 19995|round(-3) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to divide your original number, round, then multiply again by 1000:

```
{% set amount = (19995 / 1000)|round %}
{{ amount * 1000 }}
```

Rounding to the nearest 10k or 100k would be as simple as changing 1000 to 10000 or 100000 respectively.

**UPDATE:** Or you can just use Matt Rose's suggestion below.

```
{{ 19995|round(-3) }}
```

Comment: the separation of content and logic here is the best thing I've ever seen.